# Common Lisp: Are all functions built from the core functions, CAR, CDR, CONS, etc?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

True or False?

Common Lisp has a mountain of functions. All of those functions are built (or could be built) using this small set of core functions: CAR, CDR, CONS, ATOM, EQ, QUOTE, COND, LAMBDA, LABEL, NULL.

If the answer is False, can you provide an example of a function that cannot be implemented using the core functions? Perhaps the list of core functions is incomplete, and another or two additional core functions are required?

Comment: Common Lisp has some [special forms](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node59.html). Otherwise I think it's pretty much up to the implementation how it chooses to implement the standard functions/macros.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking right now at The LISP Interpreter in the LISP 1.5 Programmers Manual (appendix B). It appears that I am correct, albeit a few more functions are part of the core set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [..] All of those functions are built (or **could be built**) using [..]

The important part is the **could**, which you already figured out yourself. That (almost*) all of (a) Lisp could be built using that small set of core functions (forms) is part of the beauty of Lisp. In practice, though, the set of functions (forms) not implemented in Lisp is a *lot* larger.

Why do implementations then bother to implement that much, when they only could implement that minimal core? As a small example, think of this expression:

```
(+ 1 2)
```

You *could* implement a Lisp that uses only the small set of core functions and it would be able (given an appropriate parser for the numbers) to evaluate this expression. **But it would be painfully slow!** The systems (CPUs) that are available to us mostly provide a lot of different instructions which Lisp implementations (especially the compiling ones) try to leverage as much as possible in order to allow fast execution of Lisp programs. And, to get back to the example, that also means that one wouldn't do actual calculations using [peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) but rather use the "boolean logic arithmetic" implemented in hardware.

> If the answer is False, can you provide an example of a function that cannot be implemented using the core functions?

That's easy, how'd you implement `format`? Anything that's not part of the "algorithmic" nature of a programming language, i.e. the stuff interfacing with the "outside world", is often not implemented in itself but - being dependent on the underlying system - most often in C or assembly.

Comment: Outstanding! Thank you Daniel for your clear and detailed explanation. I appreciate it very much. What you say makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 4):

False.  Any function which deals with a datatype other than conses can not be implemented from your proposed core set: for instance important types such as `NUMBER` and `SYMBOL` can not be dealt with at all.  Any function which does I/O likewise, and probably other vast reaches of the language.

Your list sounds like it came from some incomplete description of a proposed core of Lisp 1.5.

Comment: IIRC that's the list from the original paper by McCarthy. Most (all?) types can be dealt with in some kind of peano like encoding. I/O should be the only thing that's not implementable using the given list of functions/forms.

Comment: @DanielJour: other types can't be dealt with in ways which both have reasonable time/space complexity and behave the way CL specifies.

Comment: Of course not with reasonable time/space (adding through counting and based on that multiplying by adding takes ages) but certainly with correct behavior.

Comment: @DanielJour: obviously the given set of functions is enough to specify a UTM: that's not in question.  But CL specifies, for instance, syntax, none of which can be dealt with with these functions.  If the question had been 'is this set of functions enough to implement *a* Lisp' then the answer would have been different, but CL has a detailed specification, and the set of functions is inadequate to implement that specification.